# RUBY append Hash to Array as Value - not as Reference

Tags: ruby, serialization, hashmap, copy, deep-copy

See this IRB code :

```
2.6.6 :107 > h = {}
 => {} 
2.6.6 :108 > a = []
 => [] 
2.6.6 :109 > h["name"] = "hans"
 => "hans" 
2.6.6 :110 > a << h
 => [{"name"=>"hans"}] 
2.6.6 :111 > h["name"] = "paul"
 => "paul" 
2.6.6 :112 > a
 => [{"name"=>"paul"}] 
2.6.6 :113 >
```

But this is not that what I want, when I overwrite the h Hash, I don't want to overwrite the already added value to the array ! ! !

Comment: What do you want? If you want a copy of the hash, then use `a << h.clone`.

Comment: Do you want `a #=> [{"name"=>"hans"}, {"name"=>"paul"}]`? When you give an example, you should always show the desired return value. It's also helpful to readers if you exclude the prompts (e.g., `2.6.6 :112 >`). Doing so makes what's left easier to read and allows readers to copy and paste your code without have to edit-out the the bumph.

Comment: Thanks ggorlen - the h.clone is exact what I was looking for. 
But why RUBY handles Hashes and Arrray as REFERENCES not as COPY ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted this:

```
2.6.6 :107 > h = {}
=> {} 
2.6.6 :108 > a = []
=> [] 
2.6.6 :109 > h["name"] = "hans"
=> "hans" 
2.6.6 :110 > a << h.clone
=> [{"name"=>"hans"}] 
2.6.6 :111 > h["name"] = "paul"
2.6.6 :112 > a
=> [{"name"=>"hans"}]
```

Comment: The hint from ggorlen is exact that what I want.